# No me reconoce dos componentes, a pesar de que están importados

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando unas pruebas para cargar componentes de Angular con y sin Lazy load.

En la versión sin lazy loaded, se me está produciendo un error que indica que no me reconoce ni el router-outlet ni los componetes app-cabecera y app-pie.

Sin embargo, los tengo importados y en su módulo los exporto y no me muestra error.

Este es el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las rutas que estoy utilizando son las siguientes:

```
- auth
    \login
    \registro  
    
- contacto
    
- public (app)

    \inicio

    \anuncios
        \nuevo
    
    \fiestas 
        \nueva
    
    \noticias
        \nueva
```

¿Sabéis que puede estar pasando? Por más que lo veo, no encuentro nada raro.

Esta es la versión en github:

```
https://github.com/anubedam/menu/releases/tag/v1.0-sin-lazy
```

**ANEXO: Código del ejemplo**

Incluyo el código del ejemplo para que la pregunta no pierda la consistencia en el caso de que el repositorio de Github desaparezca.

auth.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas */
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';

/* Componentes pertenecientes a AuthModule */
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RegistroComponent } from './pages/registro/registro.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes que pertenecen a Auth Module */
    LoginComponent, 
    RegistroComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Componentes pertenecientes a AuthModule */
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

auth-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes que se renderizan */
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { RegistroComponent } from './pages/registro/registro.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { 
     path: 'auth', 
     children: [
       { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
       { path: 'registro', component: RegistroComponent },
       { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
     ]
   } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

login.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Página de Login</h1>
<hr>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

registro.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Página de registro</h1>
<hr>
```

registro.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registro',
  templateUrl: './registro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registro.component.css']
})
export class RegistroComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

contacto.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Página de Contacto</h1>
<hr>
```

contacto.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.component.css']
})
export class ContactoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

shared.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Componentes pertenecientes al módulo shared */
import { CabeceraComponent } from './cabecera/cabecera.component';
import { PieComponent } from './pie/pie.component';

/* Módulo para poder realizar la navegación */
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes pertenecientes al módulo Shared */
    CabeceraComponent,
    PieComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulo que necesitan nuestros componentes */
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    /* Componentes que se utilizarán fuera de este módulo */
    CabeceraComponent,
    PieComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

cabecera.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Icono de inicio -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" 
           routerLink="/app"
           routerLinkActive="active">
           
           Inicio
        </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-bs-target="#menu-inicio">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Opciones del menú que se renderizan -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" 
             id="menu-inicio">

            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                <!-- Menú anuncios -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
                       href="#" id="menu-anuncio" 
                       role="button" 
                       data-bs-toggle="dropdown">

                       Anuncios
                    </a>

                    <!-- Opciones del desplegable -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
                        aria-labelledby="menu-anuncio">

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/anuncios"
                               routerLinkActive="active">

                                Anuncios
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/anuncios/nuevo"
                               routerLinkActive="active">

                                Nuevo anuncio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <!-- Menú fiestas -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
                       href="#" id="menu-fiestas" 
                       role="button" 
                       data-bs-toggle="dropdown">

                       Fiestas
                    </a>

                    <!-- Opciones del desplegable -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
                        aria-labelledby="menu-fiestas">

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/fiestas"
                               routerLinkActive="active">

                                Fiestas
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/fiestas/nueva"
                               routerLinkActive="active">

                               Nueva fiesta
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <!-- Menú Noticias -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" 
                       href="#" id="menu-noticias" 
                       role="button" 
                       data-bs-toggle="dropdown">

                       Noticias
                    </a>

                    <!-- Opciones del desplegable -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
                        aria-labelledby="menu-noticias">

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/noticias"
                               routerLinkActive="active">

                               Noticias
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" 
                               routerLink="/app/noticias/nueva"
                               routerLinkActive="active">
                               
                               Nueva noticia
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

cabecera.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cabecera',
  templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.css']
})
export class CabeceraComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

pie.component.css:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

pie.component.html:

```
<ul class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center py-3">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Política de privacidad</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ms-4">
        <a href="#">Cookies</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

pie.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie',
  templateUrl: './pie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie.component.css']
})
export class PieComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes que se renderizarán */
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/pages/contacto.component';

/* Módulos con las rutas hijas */
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth/auth-routing.module';
import { PublicRoutingModule } from './public/public-routing.module';

/* Rutas principales de la aplicacion */
const routes: Routes = [
  /* /auth -> Login y registro */
  /* /app  -> Rutas protegidas */
  { path: 'contacto', component: ContactoComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'auth'}   
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* Módulos que necesita mi aplicacion */
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AuthRoutingModule,
    PublicRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<!-- Navegación inicial hacia las rutas principales -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'menus';
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

/* Módulo de rutas principales */
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

/* Componentes que pertenecen al bundle principal de la aplicación */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/pages/contacto.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes que pertenecen al bundle principal */
    AppComponent,
    ContactoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulos que necesita nuestro bundle principal */
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Menus</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Aplicación de angular -->
  <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

public.component.html:

```
<!-- Cabecera -->
<!-- <app-cabecera class="fixed-top"></app-cabecera> -->
<app-cabecera></app-cabecera>

<!-- contenido principal -->
<!--<router-outlet class="contenido"></router-outlet>-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- Pie de página -->
<app-pie></app-pie>
```

public.component.css:

```
app-pie{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.contenido{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 80px auto 100px;
}
```

public.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-public',
  templateUrl: './public.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./public.component.css']
})
export class PublicComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

public.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas para public  */
import { PublicRoutingModule } from './public-routing.module';

/* Módulo shared - para poder utilizar cabecera y pie */
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

/* Componentes pertenecientes al módulo public */
import { PublicComponent } from './public.component';
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes pertenecientes a este módulo */
    PublicComponent,
    InicioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulos qu0e utiliza nuestro módulo public */
    CommonModule,
    PublicRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class PublicModule { }
```

public-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes renderizados */
import { PublicComponent } from './public.component';
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';

/* Rutas nietas de app */
import { anunciosRoutes } from './anuncios/anuncios.routes';
import { fiestasRoutes } from './fiestas/fiestas.routes';
import { noticiasRoutes } from './noticias/noticias.routes';

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: 'app',
      component: PublicComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: InicioComponent },
        { path: 'anuncios', children: anunciosRoutes },
        { path: 'fiestas', children: fiestasRoutes },
        { path: 'noticias', children: noticiasRoutes },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
      ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PublicRoutingModule { }
```

anuncios.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Todos los anuncios</h1>
<hr>
```

anuncios.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-anuncios',
  templateUrl: './anuncios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./anuncios.component.css']
})
export class AnunciosComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

nuevo-anuncio.component.html

```
<h1 class="text-center">Nuevo anuncio</h1>
<hr>
```

nuevo-anuncio.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nuevo-anuncio',
  templateUrl: './nuevo-anuncio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nuevo-anuncio.component.css']
})
export class NuevoAnuncioComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

anuncios.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas de Anuncios */
import { AnunciosRoutingModule } from './anuncios-routing.module';

/* Componentes pertenecientes al módulo anuncios */
import { AnunciosComponent } from './pages/anuncios/anuncios.component';
import { NuevoAnuncioComponent } from './pages/nuevo-anuncio/nuevo-anuncio.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes pertenecientes a este módulo */
    AnunciosComponent,
    NuevoAnuncioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulos que necesitan nuestros componentes */
    CommonModule,
    AnunciosRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AnunciosModule { }
```

anuncios.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes que se renderizan */
import { AnunciosComponent } from './pages/anuncios/anuncios.component';
import { NuevoAnuncioComponent } from './pages/nuevo-anuncio/nuevo-anuncio.component';

export const anunciosRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '', /* Path /app/anuncios */
      children: [
        { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: AnunciosComponent },
        { path: 'nuevo', component: NuevoAnuncioComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }             
      ]
    }
];
```

fiestas.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Todas las fiestas</h1>
<hr>
```

fiestas.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fiestas',
  templateUrl: './fiestas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fiestas.component.css']
})
export class FiestasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

nueva-fiesta.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Nueva fiesta</h1>
<hr>
```

nueva-fiesta.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nueva-fiesta',
  templateUrl: './nueva-fiesta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nueva-fiesta.component.css']
})
export class NuevaFiestaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

fiestas.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas de fiestas */
import { FiestasRoutingModule } from './fiestas-routing.module';

/* Componentes que pertenecen a este módulo */
import { FiestasComponent } from './pages/fiestas/fiestas.component';
import { NuevaFiestaComponent } from './pages/nueva-fiesta/nueva-fiesta.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componente del módulo fiestas */
    FiestasComponent,
    NuevaFiestaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulos que necesitan los componentes de este módulo */
    CommonModule,
    FiestasRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class FiestasModule { }
```

fiestas.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes que se renderizan */
import { FiestasComponent } from './pages/fiestas/fiestas.component';
import { NuevaFiestaComponent } from './pages/nueva-fiesta/nueva-fiesta.component';

export const fiestasRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', /* Ruta base: /app/fiestas */
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: FiestasComponent },
      { path: 'nueva', component: NuevaFiestaComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' } 
    ]
  }
];
```

inicio.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Inicio</h1>
<hr>
```

inicio.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.css']
})
export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

noticias.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Todas las noticias</h1>
<hr>
```

noticias.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-noticias',
  templateUrl: './noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./noticias.component.css']
})
export class NoticiasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

nueva-noticia.component.html:

```
<h1 class="text-center">Nueva noticia</h1>
<hr>
```

nueva-noticia.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nueva-noticia',
  templateUrl: './nueva-noticia.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nueva-noticia.component.css']
})
export class NuevaNoticiaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

noticias.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas de noticias */
import { NoticiasRoutingModule } from './noticias-routing.module';

/* Componentes del módulo de noticias */
import { NoticiasComponent } from './pages/noticias/noticias.component';
import { NuevaNoticiaComponent } from './pages/nueva-noticia/nueva-noticia.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /* Componentes que pertenecen a este módulo */
    NoticiasComponent, 
    NuevaNoticiaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /* Módulos que necesitan nuestros componentes */
    CommonModule,
    NoticiasRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class NoticiasModule { }
```

noticias.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

/* Componentes que se van a renderizar */
import { NoticiasComponent } from './pages/noticias/noticias.component';
import { NuevaNoticiaComponent } from './pages/nueva-noticia/nueva-noticia.component';

export const noticiasRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', /* Ruta base /app/noticias */
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: NoticiasComponent },
      { path: 'nueva', component: NuevaNoticiaComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }    
    ]
  }
];
```

Muchas gracias :D

Comment: ¿cómo los tienes importados? no has puesto nada de código

Comment: Hola Pablo. Puse el repo de github para no recargar demasiado la pregunta: https://github.com/anubedam/menu/tree/sin-lazy-load

Comment: Es política de este sitio no depender de terceros: si ese repositorio es eliminado o renombrado, la pregunta quedará inutilizada

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. No lo había pensado.. Voy a ponerlo como un anexo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes importar el `SharedModule` en `AuthModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/* Módulo de rutas */
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';

/* Componentes pertenecientes a AuthModule */
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegistroComponent } from './registro/registro.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegistroComponent],
  imports: [
    /* Componentes pertenecientes a AuthModule */
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    SharedModule // Agregar El Modulo Shared para poderlo usar
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Comment: Hola @Alexander Diaz. La cabecera y el pie de página sólo los utilizo en las páginas privadas (/app), pero aún así lo he puesto y sigue fallando: https://github.com/anubedam/menu/tree/sin-lazy-load. Es muy raro esto que pasa.